# How to show the amount of post that have on the site?

Tags: count

How can I make a code show the number of posts you have on my site, adding all fair categories??

Comment: Hi Pedro Quezado, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a query could give you easier customization without having to use SQL directly.

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
  'post_type'   => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'any', 
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'fields'      => 'ids',
));

$total_count = count( $posts );

print_r ( $total_count );
```

Answer (score 0):

This forum thread has a great answer: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/show-number-of-post?replies=4

Here's the code they posted for echoing the amount:

```
<?php
echo $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'");
?>
```

Comment: Thus the site is vulnerable to SQL Injection??

Comment: @PieterGoosen i can do so? `function mdv_post_count() {
 $count_posts = wp_count_posts();
 return $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
}`

Comment: @PedroQuezado jip, that would be the correct way

Comment: There is zero user supplied input to that query. It is 100% hard coded, so the protestations over safety and SQL injection are nonsense. There is no way to inject anything into that string. `wp_count_posts()` leverages caching so it is still the better way to go though.

Comment: I'm with @s_ha_dum - https://www.wordfence.com/learn/php-vulnerabilities-types-and-how-they-originate/#wf-lesson-anchor-sql-injection-or-sqli